# Function show and hide form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a Jquery function to add or remove a drop down menu based on the selection of a different drop down menu,

This is my very first time trying to use Java script, and i need a little help to get it going.

here is what i have done up to now, but i cant seem to get it to work can somone tell me where i have gone wrong?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(function remove() {

$("select#name").val();
        if (name == "United Kindom") {
                $("select.county").show();
                  }  else {
                $("select.county").hide(); });
});






<select name="ab" onchange="remove();">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, what you're using is a mash-up of Javascript and jQuery(A Javascript Library). You must understand this. Just so you know the below is jQuery, and I'll add the pure JS to the end of the post.
Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".selectWrapper").on("change", "select#ab", function(){
      $("select.county").toggle($(this).val() != "United Kindom");
   });
});

<div class="selectWrapper">
   <select id="ab">
```

This is also assuming you have
       `<select class="country">`
somewhere in your code.

//---Pure JS ----

```
   document.getElementById("ab").onchange = function(){
      var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select"), countrySelect;
      for(var x in selects){
       countrySelect = (selects[x].className == "country")? select[x] : "";
      }
      countrySelect.style.display = (this.value == "United Kindom")? 'none' : 'block';
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains a syntax error, undeclared variables and a scope problem.

Your code can be rewritten more efficiently: `$(fn)` where `fn` is a function is equivalent to `$(document).ready(fn)`. Also, the [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method can be used instead of `if-then-show-else-hide`.

### Fixed code

The inline handler did not work either, because `function remove` was defined within the `$().ready` function.

To fix the code itself, bind the event handler using jQuery, instead of using an inline handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name=ab]').change(function() {
        var name = $("select#name").val();
        $("select.county").toggle(name == "United Kindom");
    });
});
//<select name="ab">
```

### Syntax error revealed

After indenting the code properly, the syntax error can be spotted quite easily

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function remove() {
        var name = $("select#name").val();     // Prefixed "var name = "
        if (name == "United Kindom") {
            $("select.county").show();
        } else {
            $("select.county").hide();
        } // <----------- This one is missing!
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

and just a quick hint at how to make easier use of jQuery

Remember, it's the "write less, do more" library:

```
//  Easy jquery way to run when doc loaded
$(function() {
    //  you dont need to include the tag in an id selector
    // remember, any way you can select an element in css, you can do in jQuery
    $("#Country").change(function() { // here i use the .change event to know when this select box's value has actually changed to a new value
        // i'm not sure exactly what you were trying to hide and show, 
        // i couldn't fllow where vaiable `name` came from, but this is 
        // how you could easily show or hide somthing based on this select's value
        var $value = $(this).val();
        // although, if you're gonna have alot of possible ifs, 
        // i would suggest a switch statement
        switch($value) {
            case "United Kingdom":
                // here you can choose to show a specific select for UK states/countries/ares (i'm not familiar with how it works, i'm sorry)
                $("#UKStates").show();
                // if you're going to show specific, prefilled select boxes,
                // then it would be advised to include a classname on each one
                // that you can refer to in order to hide the rest
                $(".select-states").hide();
                break;
            case "United States":
                // do work
                break;
            default:
                // do work
        }
        // otherwise, if you won't have many if statements,
        // just use a regular if statment, like so:
        // if ($value == "United Kindom") {
        //     $(".county").show();
        // }
        // else {
        //     $(".county").hide();
        // }
    })
});
```

notice in my example, there is alot of commented teaching, but not alota of code.  Always remember, jQuery does all the work, just do what you need too.

Comment: You changed the meaning on the switch, there should only be two things `case "United Kingdom"` and `default`. Also, switch is slower if it has only 2-3 cases (but, after 4 you start seeing positive performance), so I wouldn't use it with this simple `ìf..else`

Comment: That's why i said `if you're gonna have alot of possible ifs`. If you only have a couple if statements, then go that direction, as I mentioned, I was only guessing at your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

You could start of by reducing your function to just this, making use of the `showOrHide` overload of [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```
function remove() {
    $("select[name='ab']").toggle($("select[name='ab']").val() === "United Kingdom");
}
```

Since you are loading jQuery, you could as well make use of its event-handling as well, instead of using inline `onchange=""`. Something like this:

```
 $(function(){ // Wait for DOM to be ready
    $("select[name='ab']").change(remove); // Attach an change-lister
 });
```

**So the complete thing would be:**

```
 $(function(){
    $("select[name='ab']").change(remove);
 });

function remove() {
    $("select[name='ab']").toggle($("select[name='ab']").val() === "United Kingdom"));
}
```